Why does the Nabazov Virus kill 47 in 5 mintues but everyone else can be infected all day?
Why does the Nabazov Virus kill 47 in 5 mintues but everyone else can be infected all day?
47 is supposed to be immune to viruses or at least more resistant, why is he weaker than everyone else when it comes to Nabazov?

There are a couple potential reasons on this Reddit thread.
Here are some gameplay focused reasons:

I’m gonna go with ‘the virus takes 5 minutes to be incurable with the vaccine’. Since 47’s job is to stop the infection from spreading, he’s technically dead/ game over.
 -Furryboh


It's just for the sake of gameplay I'm guessing.  
If everyone infected died naturally in 5 minutes it would make the virus laughably easy (albeit somewhat slow) to contain, just wait for everyone to die.  
It's the same reason that being in emetic gas fumigator in Whittleton Creek/ Haven/ Bank will kill 47, or why emetic grenade fumes don't affect 47, or why people can stay unconscious indefinitely, or the million other things that defy logical sense but are there for gameplay balance.
 -lmaogetthatbread

And here's a more lore-based (still theoretical reason) from the thread:

As I mentioned in an earlier thread, I would suspect 47s immune system has not yet been tested by something like a flu, so it would be considerably weaker against the virus. Meanwhile all these NPCs on the map have more than likely dealt with the flu before so their immune systems would be stronger.
 -Jakinator178

HeroicMe made the following reply to lmaogetthatbread


It's just for the sake of gameplay I'm guessing.

Pretty much this, but if you really need some in-lore explanation, you can always blame his 47th chromosome.  
You can also explain all the other stuff with it too :D
 -HeroicMe

but I believe this is a joke.
